# Is it possible to find the norm fuction of a space from an inner product already defined for it?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

I'm a noob on the subject of functional analysis. As the title of the question says:

*Is it possible to find the norm fuction of a space from an inner product already defined for it?*

e.gr.:

Suppose that a vector product on a space is defined as $$\langle\phi(\mathbf{x}),\phi(\mathbf{z})\rangle= \kappa(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z})$$ for a known $\kappa$ function. What would be a suitable $\|\phi(\mathbf{x})\|$ for the induced space in terms of $\kappa$?

If that's possible, would you suggest some bibliography about the question?
How could that be done?

Thanks

Comment: Take $\|x\| = \langle x,x\rangle^\frac12$. This is the norm that allows things like the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Comment: $\|x\|=\langle x,x\rangle^{1/2}$